# Can Microsoft Visual SourceSafe and GIT work next to each other?

Tags: git, versioning, visual-sourcesafe

In my company, we are working with Microsoft Visual SourceSafe.

As this is a very old system, I'd like to stop working with this and go for GIT.
On the internet, there should be plenty of explanations on how to convert the whole SourceSafe environment into GIT.

However, I'm dealing with colleagues and a boss who are very reluctant to change, and therefore, instead of forcing them into GIT, I'd like to introduce GIT on my workstation while they can keep working with SourceSafe.

This would mean that they can continue versioning with SourceSafe on the source code repository, while I do the same on the same source repository, and my changes are visible on their workstations while their changes are visible on mine.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSS cannot exclude folder ([as commented](https://discourse.codinghorror.com/t/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe/751/19) in the article "[Source Control: Anything But SourceSafe](https://blog.codinghorror.com/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe/)", from twelve+ years ago, Aug. 2006, by the very same creator of Stack Overflow, [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/about-me/)).

That means, you cannot create a `.git` subfolder (with `git init .`) directly within a checked out VSS workspace.

Plus, as described in "[Migrating from Visual SourceSafe to Git](https://accu.org/journals/overload/21/118/oldwood_1828/)" from 2013 by [Chris Oldwood](https://twitter.com/chrisoldwood), not every content from Source Safe would fit *one* Git repository (which should represent one component, not a collection of different projects).
Or would fit *any* Git repository (considering it is a source control system, and VSS could very well store large binaries).

But you still can create your Git repository anywhere you want *outside* of VSS checked out files, and use git with:

```
set GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/VSS/workspace/subfolder
git status
git add .
git commit -m "Import from VSS
...
```

Comment: I think what is being looked for is not just having the files next to each other, but some translation layer, like `git-svn` provides to mirror a Subversion repo to git.

Comment: @IMSoP no, there is no git-vss like there would be for SVN. And it is not even a good practice, considering the centralized nature of VSS: you would not want a full VSS repo into *one* Git repository anyway.

Comment: That consideration is exactly the same with SVN; it's many years since I used it, but I think the tool just lets you specify the sub-directory in the SVN repository that you want to mirror. Anyway, I was mostly pointing out that you may have misunderstood the question (unless I did) because where the .git folder is doesn't really matter if you're trying to collaborate with your colleagues, not just work around them.